# HTML 5 Double-Helix/DNA

Tags: javascript, html5, animation, canvas, svg

What would be the most cross browser friendly (IE9, Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera) way to code an animated, interactive double-helix?

HTML 5/JavaScript is fine.  Flash or Java is not.

I am unsure if canvas or svg or pure css should be considered as graphics aren't typically my thing.  In fact, I really don't know where to start here, so I probably just need a nudge in the right direction.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing 3D, you can use [HTML5 Canvas and WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL) to generate such a rendering and so forth. Interaction with the window would likely accomplished through Javascript though HTML5 may be up to that task as well.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how complicated the animation is.

If your cross browser compatibility requirement includes IE, WebGL is not an option. Your best bet is to use Canvas & Javascript.